# Why do I get a server fatal error when trying to create an instance of Google's class TextToSpeechClient on App Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, composer-php, google-text-to-speech, app.yaml

I'm getting a fatal server error when trying to create an instance of Googles's TextToSpeechClient class while deploying PHP app on App Engine flex environment. On localhost it works without any issue. Below is the error message:

> "NOTICE: PHP message:
>   PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class
>   'Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\TextToSpeechClient' not found in
>   /app/web/get_voices2.php:46"

My get_voices2.php

```
<?php
// includes the autoloader for libraries installed with composer

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once('includes/dbPDO.php');

// Imports the Cloud Client Library

use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\AudioConfig;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\AudioEncoding;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\SsmlVoiceGender;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\SynthesisInput;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\TextToSpeechClient;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\VoiceSelectionParams;
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;


if (isset($_POST['language']) && isset($_POST['quality'])) {


        $storage = new StorageClient();
        $language = $_POST['language'];
        $quality = $_POST['quality'];
        $dsn = getenv('MYSQL_DSN');
        $user = getenv('MYSQL_USER');
        $password = getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD');
        $dbh = OpenCon($dsn,$user,$password);

    echo getListVoices($language, $quality, $dbh);
}


function getListVoices($lan, $quality,$conn) {
    $optionData = '<option id = "0" disabled>Select voice</option>';

    // instantiates a client on line 46
    $client = new TextToSpeechClient(['credentials' => json_decode(file_get_contents('cred.json'), true)]);

    $response = $client->listVoices();
    $voices = $response->getVoices();
 }
```

Here is my App Engine folder structure. Please mention that app.yaml file is not in the web directory. It's in the same dir as /various and /php-docs-sample
[PHP app's web directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRL36.jpg)

My composer.json file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/cloud-speech": "^1.0.1",
        "google/gax": "^1.1",
         "grpc/grpc": "^1.4",
         "google/protobuf": "^v3.3.0",
        "google/auth": "^1.8",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "^2.0"
    }
}
```

I deploy my project on App Engine by running the command:

```
gcloud app deploy -version dev
```

I hope I gave complete information.

Comment: How is this related to Composer itself, or "app.yaml"? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just follow up my question with a solution that worked. As @Nico Haase mentioned in his answer, after executing:

```
$ composer require google/cloud-text-to-speech
```

Instead of:

```
$ composer require google/cloud-speech
```

Composer automatically added the following line to composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/cloud-text-to-speech": "^1.0"     
    }
}
```

Then the client was instantiated without any problem

```
$client = new TextToSpeechClient();
```

Comment: Good work finding the solution! Can you [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to it's [repository](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-text-to-speech), that class is given in the package `google/cloud-text-to-speech` - but according to your `composer.json`, you haven't required that package.

Why did you require `google/cloud-core` in the `require-dev` section after all? That's a good sign that you use a different set of application-specific classes for your development system than for production. Usually, this should only include stuff that is part of your development (like: debugging tools, test tools), but not those that provide the base of your application