# Trying to create an instance of Google's class TextToSpeechClient - exception: Could not construct ApplicationDefaultCredentials

Tags: php, apache, http, google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

When I try to create an instance of the Google TextToSpeechClient() I get the following exception.

exception: Could not construct ApplicationDefaultCredentials

Since - I have added the phpenv per below ?? Still having the issue.

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/macgowan/google_cloud/service-account-text-to-speech-test-00.json');
```

The following article mentions using google/cloud-text-to-speech rather than google/cloud-speech as I'm using. But again the code executes from the command line ??

[Why do I get a server fatal error when trying to create an instance of Google's class TextToSpeechClient on App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61758589/why-do-i-get-a-server-fatal-error-when-trying-to-create-an-instance-of-googles)

Some comments in the google forum
https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/AI-ML/Create-an-instance-of-TextToSpeechClient-and/m-p/421460#M314

Any help is appreciated ...

```
composer.json 
{
    "require": {
        "katzgrau/klogger": "dev-master",
        "google/cloud": "^0.156.0",
        "google/cloud-text-to-speech": "^1.0",
        "ext-bcmath" : "*"
    }
}
```

PHP implementation (exception: Could not construct ApplicationDefaultCredentials)

```
<?php
  header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
  header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-   Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

  require_once '/home/macgowan/vendor/autoload.php';

  // [START tts_synthesize_text]
  use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\AudioConfig;
  use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\AudioEncoding;
  use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\SsmlVoiceGender;
  use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\SynthesisInput;
  use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\TextToSpeechClient;
  use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\VoiceSelectionParams;

  putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/macgowan/google_cloud/service-account-text-to-speech-test-00.json'); 

try 
{
    putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/macgowan/google_cloud/service-account-text-to-speech-test-00.json'); 

    $ip = getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS');
    printf("Get env var - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: %s<br />", $ip);

    $ip = getenv('APACHE_RUN_USER');
    printf("Get env var - APACHE_RUN_USER: %s<br />", $ip);

    printf("Create the client object from the TextToSpeechClient() class <br />");
    $client = new TextToSpeechClient();

    printf("Calling: useApplicationDefaultCredentials() <br />");
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

    printf("Client object created sucessfully <br />");
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    printf("Caught exception: %s<br />", $e->getMessage());
    // echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

printf("Following Try/Catch on TextToSpeechClient() create <br />");

  $text = "Hello Joe"; 

  print('Set input text using the SynthesisInput() object' . PHP_EOL);
  $input_text = (new SynthesisInput())
     ->setText($text);

  $voice = (new VoiceSelectionParams())
      ->setLanguageCode('en-US')
      ->setSsmlGender(SsmlVoiceGender::FEMALE);

  $audioConfig = (new AudioConfig())
      ->setAudioEncoding(AudioEncoding::MP3);

  $response = $client->synthesizeSpeech($input_text, $voice, $audioConfig);
  $audioContent = $response->getAudioContent();

  file_put_contents('/home/macgowan/output.mp3', $audioContent);
  $client->close();
?>
```

Output

```
Calling: processResults2()
Inside processResults2()
Create the TextToSpeechClient() client object
Get env var - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: /Users/macgowan/google_cloud/service-account-text-to-speech-test-00.json
Get env var - APACHE_RUN_USER: www-data
Create the client object from the TextToSpeechClient() class
Caught exception: Could not construct ApplicationDefaultCredentials
Following Try/Catch on TextToSpeechClient() create
```

Comment: A 500 error could mean basically anything, so answering this would be a very dull guessing game. You need to look in your error log for what the actual error was; read it carefully, search this site for similar error messages, and if you're still stuck paste the exact text here for us to help you with.

Comment: Could you ensure if you are correctly initializing your client using `$client = new Google\Client()` and 
`$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials()` as per [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-service-accounts) documentation?

Comment: Thanks Sakahi - I have added the putenv() and then the create statement per the documentation that you linked to ... getting the exception `Could not construct ApplicationDefaultCredentials` - also you will notice I have added some logging to display that the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` - so this seems ok ??

Comment: I can see in your code `$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials()` is commented out. Just to clarify at my end, are you still getting credential error upon setting `$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials()` after creating new client?

Comment: Thanks Sakahi for taking a look - The exception occurs on the call to create the client object `$client = new TextToSpeechClient()`  ... so I never get to the call to set the useApplicationDefaultCredentials  `$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials()` Per a comment from the google forum - I did add the `"google/cloud-text-to-speech": "^1.0"` - to the composer ... also did not seem to help ... maybe there is a different class to instantiate rather than `TextToSpeechClient` ... I'll keep looking - any ideas are appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

To generalize the answer for this issue:

The Google Cloud PHP library uses [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts) credentials to connect to Google Cloud services. When running on Compute Engine the credentials will be discovered automatically. When running on other environments, the Service Account credentials can be specified by providing the path to the [JSON keyfile](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/managing-service-account-keys) for the account (or the JSON itself) in environment variables.

The Google Cloud PHP library discovers Credentials in the following order:

1. Specify credentials in code
2. Discover credentials path in environment variables
3. Discover credentials file in the Cloud SDK's path
4. Discover GCE credentials

Each of these are mentioned [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/main/AUTHENTICATION.md) in detail.

Example of client authentication:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\AudioConfig;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\AudioEncoding;
...

// Authenticating with a keyfile path.
$textToSpeechClient = new TextToSpeechClient([
    'keyFilePath' => '/path/to/keyfile.json'
]);
```

You can also refer [Authentication with service accounts for PHP client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-service-accounts).